# React onclick function running automatically wihout clicking

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

My Problem is:

I have react code that communicates with a smart contract.
When i start the server the oncklick function openLong() runs automatically(multiple times-> 3 transactions in Metamask) before i even click the button and when i click the button nothing happens. Why this strange behaviour?

```
import react, { useState } from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

export default function KwentaOptimism() {
  let provider = window.ethereum;
  let selectedAccount;

  if (typeof provider !== 'undefined') {
    provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }).then((accounts) => {
      selectedAccount = accounts[0];
      console.log(`Selected account is ${selectedAccount}`);
    });
  }

  const web3 = new Web3(provider);

  async function getNetworkID() {
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    return networkId;
  }

  async function loadContract() {
    let address = '0x1e28378F64bC04E872a9D01Eb261926717346F98';
    let chainlinkFutureContractABI = [
      {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [
          { internalType: 'int256', name: 'marginDelta', type: 'int256' },
        ],
        name: 'transferMargin',
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'function',
      },
    ];
    var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    Contract.setProvider(web3);
    var chainlinkFutureContract = new Contract(
      chainlinkFutureContractABI,
      address
    );

    return await chainlinkFutureContract;
  }

  async function openLong() {
    let linkContract = await loadContract();
    linkContract.methods
      .transferMargin('100000000000000000000')
      .send({ from: '0xce05626e35c053995d4988b75af85e2eb7251b3c' });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <button onclick={openLong()}>Chainlink Long</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use onClick in react.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51832797/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this, you basically call the function. Remove the parenthesis, like on the second line:

```
 <button onclick = {openLong()}>Chainlink Long</button>
 <button onClick={openLong}>Chainlink Long</button>
```

Also, try onClick intead of onclick.

Sometimes you want to pass arguments into a function like this. In those cases, you can do like this:

```
<button onClick={() => openLong(arguments)}>Chainlink Long</button>
```

Comment: and if you want to pass some parameters then call it like this 
 <button onclick = {()=>{openLong(param1, param2)}}>Chainlink Long</button>